# Win32 эмуляция нажатия клавиш без прав администратора

Tags: c#, winapi

Можно ли как то реализовать эмуляцию нажатия клавиш без прав администратора?

так все работает только через админа:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void keybd_event(uint bVk, uint bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);

        private const int VK_VOLUME_DOWN = 0xAE;
        private const int VK_VOLUME_UP = 0xAF;
        private const int VK_VOLUME_MUTE = 0xAD;

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            keybd_event(VK_VOLUME_UP, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            keybd_event(VK_VOLUME_DOWN, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            keybd_event(VK_VOLUME_MUTE, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `keybd_event` устарел, рекомендуется использовать `SendInput`.
2. Есть такая библиотека в NuGet - [InputSimulator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/InputSimulator/), уже готовое для использования на базе того же `SendInput`.
3. Ничего из перечисленного не требует прав администратора. Вероятно это особенность приложения, реакцию которого вы ожидаете на клавиши.
4. После нажатия на клавишу ее надо отпустить.
5. У вас неверная сингатура метода при импорте - [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event), [2](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.keybd_event).

Самый простой пример.

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

private const byte VK_VOLUME_UP = 0xAF;

private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0x00;
private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x02;

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    keybd_event(VK_VOLUME_UP, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
    await Task.Delay(50);
    keybd_event(VK_VOLUME_UP, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
}
```

Comment: 1 SendImput тоже работает только через администратора. 3. Ожидаю реакцию системы на регулировку звука.  5. Пример который я привел полностью рабочий.

Comment: Нашел причину того что работало только от админа... У меня клавиатура Xiaomi без мультимедийных клавиш. Я переопределил некоторые F* клавиши как мультимедийные. и этот скрипт перебивал команды